# cannot pass array to webservice in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, web-services

friends i am trying to pass an array to asp webservice method from my console application the error is that 
"The best overloaded method has some invalid arguments "

Below is console side in which function i am passing array is giving error.

```
int[] t = new int[6];
ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient client=new ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient();
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
  t[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
client.bublesort(t);    //Here is the error in passing to webservice method
```

On other hand my WEBSERVICE method code is that
    int temp = 0;

```
[WebMethod]
public int[] bublesort(int[] arr)      
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 6; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j])
            {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: cannot pass the array into the method.method is in webservice...the error is that..
"The best overloaded method has some invalid arguments "

Comment: What is the method's signature on the client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is that you have created ASMX web service and tried to add as Service Reference.

If you check method signature in your client it is not accepting Array of integer. Instead of this it has  ServiceReference1.ArrayOfInt class object.

```
ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient client=new ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient();
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
  t[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
ServiceReference1.ArrayOfInt item = new ServiceReference1.ArrayOfInt();
item.AddRange(t);
ServiceReference1.ArrayOfInt result = client.bublesort(item);
foreach (var i in result)
{
  Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for solution , but problem is now that it is  not giving output when i write as console.writeline(client.bubblesort(item)); to display sorted array it is giving me this in output. "ServiceReference1.ArrayofInt".

Comment: Check updated code and also you can also verify that what is return type ?

Comment: Oh i am very very very very much thankfull to you dear...you have solved my problem ..... again thanks to you....